# How does EOS create signature?

Tags: nodeos, eosjs, keosd

For signing serialized transaction it needs make sha256 one time, but EOS returns signature longer than 64 symbols. My question is - what is additional info added to the signature?

Answer (score 1):

A transaction signature is formed of a `SIG_` prefix, a part that defines which curve algorithm was used to create the signature e.g; `K1` or `R1`, and the base58 encoded SHA256 hash. e.g; `SIG_K1_{base58_hash}`

A signature being constructed in swift
- https://github.com/memtrip/eos-swift/blob/master/eosswift/eos-core/encode/Base58.swift#L19